# Debugging Exceptions in Async Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

Back when I used synchronous methods in code using ASP.NET MVC 3, if an exception was thrown, it wasn't hard to figure out where it came from in my exception filter.  Just looking at the stack trace was enough.

When an `async` method in ASP.NET Web API throws an exception, however, the exception details are less useful, since the stack trace doesn't show where the exception was thrown from:

```
System.ArgumentException: title must not be empty.
Parameter name: title    
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__1.MoveNext()
```

Currently, I have to look at all the exceptions with this message and guess which one was thrown based on the request URI and what's going on behind the scenes, or try and reproduce the bug locally with a debugger attached.

MSDN has an article detailing a couple strategies for getting a casualty chain: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891052.aspx3.  From my understanding, I have two choices:

- Use System.Diagnostics.EventListener and take a performance hit at run-time
- Create an extension method and use it with every `await` call

Is there a better way to log more helpful details about what threw this exception? Having the casualty chain would be nice, but just getting the exception source would be fine (what type and method this was thrown in).

Comment: Just FYI...We have made improvements in post-5.0 where the stack trace is preserved and you get better details..

Comment: @KiranChalla Great!  Looking forward to improvements in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile against .NET 4.5.1 rather than 4.5 and you will generally get better exception traces with async.

Comment: That was it!  After updating .NET on the server, I now get stack traces that include much more information about where the exception was thrown.

Answer (score 3):

Both of your options cause run-time overhead.

A third option (which also causes run-time overhead) is to use my [AsyncDiagnostics](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncDiagnostics) library. I'm partial to that one (naturally), but every option introduces run-time overhead.

Comment: It looks like that library has a dependency on PostSharp.  Is there a version of your library that doesn't have this dependency?

Comment: @Dustin: No. It uses Postshap to inject hooks around the `async` methods.

Comment: I won't be able to use PostSharp, so I'll go with one of the methods recommended in that MSDN article I linked to.  I'll mark this one as accepted since you answered my question indirectly: there is not a way to accomplish what I want in ASP.NET Web API without taking a third-party dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy the PDB for your assembly to the same folder where the DLL is deployed, the exception stack trace should include file and line number information. In particular, the `MoveNext()` calls will be located within your `async` methods.

If optimizations are enabled for your assembly (and they likely are for Release builds), the line numbers may be occasionally inaccurate, so keep that in mind if you still can't figure out the problem based on the line number it tells you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to in this case.  PDBs are currently deployed to the server this code runs on.  All I get in the exception that's passed to my exception filter is the stack trace detailed above.